# special characters validation reactive forms

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

I want not allow the user insert special characters i use this

```
 this.schedulerForm = this.fb.group({

        name: [this._schedule.Name, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/[!^\w\s]$/)] ]]
    });
```

its work for if the user for example type @@,
but the problem is that if the user type for example- @@dewq -its valid! how the pattern have to be to invalid it also?

thanks!

Comment: What is allowed to match?

Comment: i want the allowed all except the special characters

Comment: You want to match wordcharacters and whitespaces? [`^[\w\s]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/O1k8FT/1/)

Comment: I believe you need `Validators.pattern("[\\w\\s]+")` or `Validators.pattern(/^[\w\s]+$/)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex `[!^\w\s]$` matches 1 character from the character class `[!^\w\s]`  at the end of the line `$` so it matches the last character in `@@dewq` but is does not match the last character in `@@`

If you want to match only whitespaces and word characters you could specify those in a character class and use a quantifier to repeat those one or more times using `+`.

[`^[\w\s]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/O1k8FT/1/)

**Explanation**

- `^` Assert the start of the line
- `[\w\s]+` Match one or more times a word character or a whitespace character
- `$` Assert the end of the line

Answer (score 1):

The pattern must start with a `^` to denote a word start and `+` to allow multiple characters:

```
Validators.pattern(/^[\w\s]+$/)
```

Comment: This dissallows (does this word exist?) empty strings.I'd recommend using `*` instead of `+`, with `^...$` you match the whole string anyway. .... Is this relevant in angular?

Comment: thanks for the answer. with this pattern also for example aa its not valid.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize there were multiple problems with the Regex in first place, sorry.